# Changing page without opening the menu

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am trying to change the page without opening the menu. I am using the flutter plugin called Hidden Drawer Menu (https://pub.dev/packages/hidden_drawer_menu).

I have my page where I have the menu controller and I just call it to switch between pages, but I also want to add quick button routes to go straight to some pages that they are in under this Hidden Drawer Menu.

They way I do that is using their provider like this:

`setSelectedMenuPosition(anyposition)`

When I do this, it switches the page but it also opens the Menu Drawer and this is something I don't want to do. I just want to switch the page without opening the menu. Any idea?

Thanks!!!

Comment: you can navigate to any page without using that package at all. Simply use Navigator.of(context).push(yourPage);

Comment: @Darish I can't since I need to stay in the same page with the menu button in the Appbar. If I do a Navigator.of(context).push(myPage), I will lose the functionality of the icon to toggle the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Just it canse someone is trying to do the same... I had to do a work around.

Create an optional variable called position in your main.dart file where you call the Menu. In case you initialize this variable, open a new main.dart as a Navigator.replace and then initalize this page with the page you want since you know you initialized the variable "position".